# bluemix fitbit step contest

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, iot

I have recreated the the fitbit contest app by downloading the existing code as described in the [IBM Developerworks training material](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-fitbitcontest-app).
The App on Bluemix is running fine and it seems all the necessary services have been added correctly.

When I select my url https://myappname.mybluemix.net/ I get the Welcome page correctly.

The trouble I have is the couple of steps that initialise the database and twitter etc.
This requires me to enter https://myappname.mybluemix.net/php/sqlinit.php (for database initialisation), when I do this I get a "Server Error" page with an "error 500" statement but not much else.

This is on chrome but IE is the same.

When I use the developer tool on chrome it seems to indicate the sqlinit.php is  blank which suggests to me that the App cannot find this particular file or the /PHP/ directory.

As I have not altered the directory structure I would assume it is something else.

I did move the PHP directory to the root at one point and push the code but that did nothing so I moved it back.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the log? You can get the logs by using:
cf logs APP_NAME

Comment: dooohhh - a smart person would have remembered to check the logs.  Unfortunately, I have to do things the hard way.  Checking them now and there are some lines that need investigation.  Thanks.  I'll post my results directly.

Comment: So the log basically says the following **bold**PHP Notice:  Undefined index: FITBIT_CONSUMER_KEY

Comment: So the log basically says the following **PHP Notice:  Undefined index: FITBIT_CONSUMER_KEY** for the key and secret.  for some reason the fitbit keys are not coming from the VCAP_SERVICES inot the Array  even though they are definitely there.  I did a work around which was to hard code the key and secret - not a solution - but my PHP skills need more work.  Thanks for the guidance.